# How to set recently 3 days in dateRangeInput of shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to show the recently 3 days as default values in dateRangeInput. Now the Sys.Date() to set start, end and max. This is my ui.R and server.R

ui.R

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

    # Application title
    headerPanel('dateRangeInput'),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of observations
    sidebarPanel(
        wellPanel(
            dateRangeInput('days', 'Select a date range:', 
                start = Sys.Date() - 3,
                end = Sys.Date(), 
                max = Sys.Date()))
    ),
    mainPanel()
))
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) 
{

})
```

However, the date are froze in the date of Shiny App started when date is changed. See screenshot.

How could I dynamically change the start, end and max according to current date? Thanks for any suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add an observe into server.R. Not sure this is the best solution.

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) 
{

    observe({
        updateDateRangeInput(session, "days",
            start = Sys.Date() - 3,
            end = Sys.Date(), 
            max = Sys.Date())
    })
})
```